# How to group same values?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

If the user makes a reservation, new data is generated as much as the bicycle types. The database grows vertically. When the reservation is made, it produces a unique key and it is constant for that moment. For example:
new reservation was made. 'Random0124' and type_1: 2 quantity, type_2: 2 quantity. This means type_1 + type_2 times new rows stored in database. All data are the same except for the bicycle type.

'bicycle_type' => 1 relational data. This is not quantity this means type_1 or something like that.

Basically I want to group with the reservation number. I want to return bicycle types and totals belonging to that reservation number.

I want to combine everything because all the data is the same except bicycle_type.

I have an array like this:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:12 [▼
    "id" => 13
    "reservation_number" => "58f382bfc4e52"
    "bicycle_type" => 1
    "start_date" => "2017-04-23 12:00:00"
    "stop_date" => "2017-04-23 13:00:00"
    "identity_number" => "11111111110"
    "name_lastname" => "John Doe"
    "email" => "John@doe.com"
    "phone" => "(124) 124 12 41"
    "is_complete" => 1
    "created_at" => "2017-04-16 17:42:21"
    "updated_at" => "2017-04-16 17:42:21"
  ]
  1 => array:12 [▼
    "id" => 14
    "reservation_number" => "58f382bfc4e52"
    "bicycle_type" => 1
    "start_date" => "2017-04-23 12:00:00"
    "stop_date" => "2017-04-23 13:00:00"
    "identity_number" => "11111111110"
    "name_lastname" => "John Doe"
    "email" => "John@doe.com"
    "phone" => "(124) 124 12 41"
    "is_complete" => 1
    "created_at" => "2017-04-16 17:42:21"
    "updated_at" => "2017-04-16 17:42:21"
  ]
  2 => array:12 [▼
    "id" => 15
    "reservation_number" => "58f382bfc4e52"
    "bicycle_type" => 2
    "start_date" => "2017-04-23 12:00:00"
    "stop_date" => "2017-04-23 13:00:00"
    "identity_number" => "11111111110"
    "name_lastname" => "John Doe"
    "email" => "John@doe.com"
    "phone" => "(124) 124 12 41"
    "is_complete" => 1
    "created_at" => "2017-04-16 17:42:21"
    "updated_at" => "2017-04-16 17:42:21"
  ]
]
```

How can i organize this collection like this:

```
array:1 [▼
  '58f382bfc4e52' => array:12 [▼
    "id" => 13
    "reservation_number" => "58f382bfc4e52"
    "bicycle_types" => [
        '1' => [
            'total' => 2,
        ],
        '2' => [
            'total' => 1
        ]
    ]  
    "start_date" => "2017-04-23 12:00:00"
    "stop_date" => "2017-04-23 13:00:00"
    "identity_number" => "11111111110"
    "name_lastname" => "John Doe"
    "email" => "John@doe.com"
    "phone" => "(124) 124 12 41"
    "is_complete" => 1
    "created_at" => "2017-04-16 17:42:21"
    "updated_at" => "2017-04-16 17:42:21"
  ]
]
```

Comment: Your question, *I think*, is not clear enough.

Comment: I organized the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the loop :

```
<?php

$as = [
            0 => [
                "id"                 => 13,
                "reservation_number" => "58f382bfc4e52",
                "bicycle_type"       => 1,
                "start_date"         => "2017-04-23 12:00:00",
                "stop_date"          => "2017-04-23 13:00:00",
                "identity_number"    => "11111111110",
                "name_lastname"      => "John Doe",
                "email"              => "John@doe.com",
                "phone"              => "(124) 124 12 41",
                "is_complete"        => 1,
                "created_at"         => "2017-04-16 17:42:21",
                "updated_at"         => "2017-04-16 17:42:21",
            ],
            1 => [
                "id"                 => 14,
                "reservation_number" => "58f382bfc4e52",
                "bicycle_type"       => 1,
                "start_date"         => "2017-04-23 12:00:00",
                "stop_date"          => "2017-04-23 13:00:00",
                "identity_number"    => "11111111110",
                "name_lastname"      => "John Doe",
                "email"              => "John@doe.com",
                "phone"              => "(124) 124 12 41",
                "is_complete"        => 1,
                "created_at"         => "2017-04-16 17:42:21",
                "updated_at"         => "2017-04-16 17:42:21"
            ],
            2 => [
                "id"                 => 15,
                "reservation_number" => "58f382bfc4e52",
                "bicycle_type"       => 2,
                "start_date"         => "2017-04-23 12:00:00",
                "stop_date"          => "2017-04-23 13:00:00",
                "identity_number"    => "11111111110",
                "name_lastname"      => "John Doe",
                "email"              => "John@doe.com",
                "phone"              => "(124) 124 12 41",
                "is_complete"        => 1,
                "created_at"         => "2017-04-16 17:42:21",
                "updated_at"         => "2017-04-16 17:42:21",
            ],
        ];

        $result = [];

        foreach ( $as as $a ) {
        $reservationNumber = $a['reservation_number'];
        // Check if reservation number is exists in the result array or not.
        if ( ! isset($result[$reservationNumber]) ) {
            // If its not available we assign the current array to result.
            $result[$reservationNumber] = $a;
            $result[$reservationNumber]['bicycle_type'] = [];
        }

        // We check if bicycle_type is exists in the result having reservationNumber.
        // If its available we increment the value, otherwise initialize it with 1;
        if (isset($result[$reservationNumber]['bicycle_type'][$a['bicycle_type']])) {
            $result[$reservationNumber]['bicycle_type'][$a['bicycle_type']]['total'] += 1;
        } else {
            $result[$reservationNumber]['bicycle_type'][$a['bicycle_type']]['total'] = 1;
        }

    }

echo "<pre>";
        print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: Please explain why this would help the SO. Although it looks like your code should work, just flashing out some code is in most situations not helpful

Comment: @giorgio I understand your concern. But guy asked for help to make the code which generate given result. There wasn't anything to explain. But As said in programming you must comment your code so that everyone can understand it. I added comments the for loop.

Comment: there's _always_ something to explain, especially if someone asks for help, which is an indication he or she does not understand how something works.

Comment: I added detail about what am i trying to do. I don't know how to make this is possible.